How can I find the average cheapest item by month and day from a list of items using SQL?
I have a list of items along with the price of each, the day they were sold, the date they were sold on, and where they were sold. I am trying to figure out what is the average cheapest price for each item and what day and month is it the cheapest on. The items do have duplicates in the list of course because they are sold in multiple places at different days and months throughout the year.
Here is an image of the first few lines of the raw data 
This is the statement I tried to use:
SELECT Grocery_Item, Store_Name, MONTH(Sales_Date) AS Month, Sales_Day, Sales_Price
FROM Grocery_Data
WHERE Sales_Price < (SELECT AVG(Sales_Price) FROM Grocery_Data)
ORDER BY Grocery_Item, Sales_Price;

The idea was to try to build a subquery that can take the sales price, then average that price and return any results less than that sales price. I was trying to have the logic be defined more along the lines of calculating the average sales price first then the lowest price using the function but I kept getting errors with that. I also tried this way with the idea of finding the average price then building a subquery to pull the cheapest price using this:
SELECT Grocery_Item, MONTH(Sales_Date) AS Month, Sales_Date,ROUND(AVG(DISTINCT Sales_Price), 2) AS Avg_Sales_Price FROM Grocery_Data GROUP BY Grocery_Item, Month, Sales_Date HAVING AVG(Sales_Price)(SELECT MIN(Avg_Sales_Price) FROM (SELECT Grocery_Item, AVG(Sales_Price) AS Avg_Sales_Price FROM Grocery_Data GROUP BY Grocery_Item) AS Subquery) ORDER BY Avg_Sales_Price;

I got no results with that.
I also tried this way but I kept getting an error:
SELECT Store_Name, Grocery_Item, Month, Sales_Day, AVG_Sales_Price
FROM (
    SELECT Store_Name, Grocery_Item, MONTH(Sales_Date) AS Month, Sales_Day,
        ROUND(AVG(Sales_Price), 2) AS AVG_Sales_Price,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Grocery_Item ORDER BY AVG(Sales_Price)) AS rank
    FROM Grocery_Data
    GROUP BY Grocery_Item, Month, Sales_Day
) ranked_data
WHERE rank = 1;

Here is an image of the first few lines of my results:
The image shows results from what I used. It seems close to what I am looking for but I would still have to export in excel to finish the rest of what I am looking for. I am hoping there is way to do this without having to export the data. I am a beginner at this as well so any advice would be helpful!!

"I got no results from that" - you should have gotten a syntax error, are you missing a < or somehing in AVG(Sales_Price)(SELECT MIN?

"I kept getting an error" - please always show the full exact error message you get when you are asking for help involving an error

"average cheapest price for each item" - I don't understand this.  please give some examples?

Also you are correct that statement did return a syntax error.  The statment I used after getting that error is:   SELECT Grocery_Item, MONTH(Sales_Date) AS Month, Sales_Date, ROUND(AVG(DISTINCT Sales_Price), 2) AS Avg_Sales_Price FROM
Grocery_Data GROUP BY Grocery_Item, Month, Sales_Date HAVING AVG(Sales_Price) = (SELECT MIN(Avg_Sales_Price) FROM (SELECT Grocery_Item,  AVG(Sales_Price) AS Avg_Sales_Price FROM Grocery_Data GROUP BY Grocery_Item) AS Subquery) ORDER BY
Avg_Sales_Price;

So the question comes from a practice question I was working on to sharpen my skills. This is the exact question :  If you wanted to buy each item at its average cheapest, which month and day in the week
would you suggest buying each item on?

oh, looking for each item which month+weekday it historically is cheapest?  or for each item, for each month, which weekday it is historically cheapest?

My guess is looking for each item which month and weekday it was historically the cheapest.

So I did get the answer to my question outside of Stack Overflow. I can't remember the solution I was shown but I get the logic and was able to come up with something myself that was close to the asnswer I was shown. When I first attenpted this, I misunderstood the question which threw off my logic for SQL. But I am glad I was able to learn a solutionenter code here. SO here it is for anyone who ever gets a question like this!!
SELECT
    g.Grocery_Item,
    g.Sales_Day AS Day,
    MONTH(g.Sales_Date) AS Month,
    MIN(g.Sales_Price) AS Min_Price
FROM
    Grocery_Data g
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
        Grocery_Item,
        MIN(Sales_Price) AS Min_Price
    FROM
        Grocery_Data
    GROUP BY
        Grocery_Item
) min_prices ON g.Grocery_Item = min_prices.Grocery_Item AND g.Sales_Price = min_prices.Min_Price
GROUP BY
    g.Grocery_Item, Day, Month
ORDER BY
    g.Grocery_Item, Month, Day;

